# How to make a field of a model form read-only when a certain field of an instance is True (Django)?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So lets say I have these classes in my `models.py`:

```
class Result(models.Model):
  grade = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  checked = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False) 
  checker = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class User(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

And lets say i have a model form in my `forms.py`:

```
class EnterResult(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Result
       exclude = ['checked']
```

I know to pass an instance of a form in `views.py` you have to:

```
result = Result.objects.get(pk=pk)
form = EnterResult(instance=result)
return render(request, ...)
```

Now how do i make ***checker*** a read-only input when the instance that is passed has it's field `checked = True`. I feel like it has something to do with overriding the `___init___(self, *args, **kwargs)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, overriding `__init__` for your form is the thing to do.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
    if instance and instance.checked:
        self.fields["checker"].disabled = True
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#disabled